# Moqed method returning null instead of string

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm using Moq for some C# testing. For some reason, I'm getting a null back instead of a string. I'm trying to test

```
public void Foo(IData data){
    _value = data.GetValue<T>(someString);
}

interface IData
{
    T GetValue<T>(string someString);
}
```

and in my test code I have

```
Mock<IData> dataMock = new Mock<IData>();
dataMock.Setup(x => x.GetValue<string>(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns("blah");
Foo(dataMock.Object);
```

But when I step through, `_value` gets assigned null. Shouldn't it be assigned `"blah"`?

Comment: Can you share your actual test? What is `<T>` in your test?

Comment: share some more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the generic `T` parameter in your call to `GetValue` is not `string`, so the Setup condition is not matched. By default Moq will return default values (`null` in this case) from method calls that haven't been explicitly Setup, unless you tell it to be "strict."

```
// tell Moq to throw an exception if someone calls a method that you haven't `Setup`
Mock<IData> dataMock = new Mock<IData>(MockBehavior.Strict);
```

Comment: You're more or less right. T was not an object, but the parameter was a string. So `It.IsAny<string>` matched fine, but the `<string>` infront of it should have been `<object>`. Update you're answer and Ill accept it.